# How to write Scala recursion with for/yield?

Tags: scala, for-loop, recursion, yield

I have the following list of pairs (key,id):

```
val pairs =  List(('a',1), ('a',2), ('b',1), ('b',2))
```

I need to generate all combinations of pairs when the keys are different
so the expected output is:

```
List(
  List(),
  List(('a', 1)),
  List(('a', 2)),
  List(('b', 1)),
  List(('a', 1), ('b', 1)),
  List(('a', 2), ('b', 1)),
  List(('b', 2)),
  List(('a', 1), ('b', 2)),
  List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))
)
```

Note `(List(('a',1),('a',2))` should Not be part of the output so using Scala `List.combinations` is not an option

I currently have the following code:

```
def subSeq (xs: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char,Int)] = {
  xs match {
    case Nil => List()
    case y::ys => {
      val eh = xs.filter (c => c._1 == y._1)
      val et = xs.filter (c => c._1 != y._1)
      for (z: (Char,Int) <- eh) yield z :: subSeq(et)
    }
  }
}
```

But I get an error saying `List[List[(Char,Int)]] does not match List[(Char,Int)]`

Comment: Your return type does not conform to the output you provided. If you want `List(List(), ...` as output, maybe you should return `List[List[(Char, Int)]]`?. Also a tip: you can use `list.flatten` to translate `List[List[T]]` into `List[T]`

Comment: flatten does resolve the type mismatch but yield the wrong result - ```List((a,1), (b,1), (c,1), (b,2), (c,1), (a,2), (b,1), (c,1), (b,2), (c,1))```  which is list of pairs and not list of List of list of combinations

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably trying to do is this:

```
def subSeq (xs: List[(Char, Int)]): List[List[(Char,Int)]] = {
  xs match {
    case Nil => List(List())
    case y::ys => {
      val eh: List[(Char, Int)] = xs.filter (c => c._1 == y._1)
      val et = xs.filter (c => c._1 != y._1)
      val t = subSeq(et)
      t ++ (for {
        z: (Char,Int) <- eh
        foo <- t
      } yield z :: foo)
    }
  }
}
```

Your method has to return a List of Lists as that is what you are interested in. So when building up your combinations you have to iterate over the result from your recursion step.

A way using API functions would be to do it like this:

```
val sets = (0 to 2).flatMap{pairs.combinations}.toSet
sets.map{_.toMap}
```

Or this if you need the output as lists:

```
sets.map{_.toMap.toList}.toList
```

Obviously this will build more combinations than you need at first and then filter stuff out. If performance is an issue and the input does not contain any redundancies, the direct implementation is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

eventually I used the `combinations` function from Scala and filtered out the non relevant matches by this filter function

```
def filterDup(xs: List[(Char,Int)]) : Boolean = {
    xs.map(x => x._1).size == xs.map(x => x._1).toSet.size
  }
```

and used it as followes:

```
((0 to 3).flatMap(pairs.combinations(_)) filter( filterDup(_))).toList
```